# Resize PictureBox as resizing the form

Tags: c#, .net, resize, picturebox, image

I'm loading multiple images into a `Panel` (multiple `PictureBoxes` inside a `Panel`) and would like to resize the images as the windows form is resized.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (string filename in ofdmulti.FileNames){
    picbox[i] = new PictureBox();
    picbox[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 256);
    picbox[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    picbox[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    i++;
}
```

But then I don't see the multiple images, just one and stretched fully, what may be wrong?

Comment: @Skippy Looks like C# to me

Comment: DockStyle.Fill enlarges a control to fill the entirety of its parent control.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues with your code.  First off, this line of code will ensure that you only see one `PictureBox`...likely the last one you added:

```
picbox[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Second, I don't see that you are setting the `PictureBox` `Location`, so they are all going to `Point(0, 0)`, meaning they would overlap to some extent even regardless of the `Dock` setting.

If you are trying to get a nice arrangement, such as Tiled, then you could use a `TableLayoutPanel`.  That would allow you to describe a grid pattern with the `Rows` and `Columns` and then add your `PictureBox` controls to the grid.

There are other options, of course, depending upon your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
First of all, this is C# .NET
I used a TableLayoutPanel to include the pictureboxes and works preety well, I now place them in rows and columns using the method "Add" of the tablelayoutpanel.
Now, if I set the property of the tablelayoutpanel to AutoScroll=True then it won't automatically resize the images as it adds scroll bars (vertical and horizontal). What's the best way to scroll through images withouth having the scroll bars in a TableLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Replace picturebox.Image with Your resized Image, and use sizemode.AutoSize!